# I get 'decimal.Decimal' object is not callable when testing code

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I've got in a function a call to `decimal.Decimal` function and it works fine always, but If I make a test and make a call to this function, then I get this error:

```
'decimal.Decimal' object is not callable
```

Code:

```
import decimal


class Stats:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__id = None
        self.__t2p_conv = 0
        self.__t2p_int = 0
        self.__t2p_percentage = 0.00

    def __del__(self):
        del self.id
        del self.t2p_conv
        del self.t2p_int
        del self.t2p_percentage


    """Properties"""
    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.__id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, id):
        self.__id = id

    @id.deleter
    def id(self):
        del self.__id

    @property
    def t2p_conv(self):
        return self.__t2p_conv

    @t2p_conv.setter
    def t2p_conv(self, total):
        self.__t2p_conv += total

    @t2p_conv.deleter
    def t2p_conv(self):
        del self.__t2p_conv

    @property
    def t2p_int(self):
        return self.__t2p_int

    @t2p_int.setter
    def t2p_int(self, total):
        self.__t2p_int += total

    @t2p_int.deleter
    def t2p_int(self):
        del self.__t2p_int

    @property
    def t2p_percentage(self):
        return self.__t2p_percentage

@t2p_percentage.getter
def t2p_percentage(self):
    decimal.getcontext().prec = 4
    print(f"t2p_conv: {self.t2p_conv} - t2p_int: {self.t2p_int}")
    return decimal.Decimal(self.t2p_conv/self.t2p_int)*100

@t2p_percentage.deleter
def t2p_percentage(self):
    del self.__t2p_percentage
```

And the code of the test is:

```
import unittest
from play_by_play.stats import Stats


class TestStats(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_t2p(self):
        s = Stats()
        s.t2p_conv = 1
        s.t2p_int = 3
        print(f"result: {s.t2p_percentage()}")
```

Why Have I got the error and not the result?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the entire error message? What line causes the error?

Comment: `t2p_percentage` is a *property*, you're trying to call the value it returns.

Comment: print(f"result: {s.t2p_percentage}")    remove parentheses.

Comment: @RocketNikita But, If I remove the parentheses I'm not calling the function t2p_percentage().

Comment: This looks like you're trying to write C++ in Python. You don't need `__del__` or any of those properties - there's no point pretending at privacy if you're just going to expose getters and setters and deleters for everything anyway, and `__del__` is a finalizer, not a destructor - it actually makes reclaiming memory **less** efficient.

Comment: make it not a property

Comment: @JoséCarlos I am unable to recreate the problem. I get an error "NameError: name 't2p_percentage' is not defined" when I copy/paste your code and run it. Double check that your indentation is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlos Also be sure you try Rocket Nikita's suggestion to remove the parentheses. If you are surprised when it works, then go back and figure out why.

Comment: If I remove like a property works fine. Thanks @RocketNikita for your appreciated help!!!

Comment: looking at this closer, those properties are a lot weirder than I first thought - two of them are *incrementing* in the setter? That's confusing and bug-prone. And there's a `self.__t2p_percentage` that isn't actually doing anything useful.

Comment: Hi @user2357112supportsMonica the properties t2p_conv and t2p_int start with initial values 0. Then you can add a number to this value and later you could be add another number to this properties. In any moment, you could have something like that t2p_conv = 3 and t2p_int = 7. The "property" t2p_percentage tried to return the % but it doesn't work like property. It's better to remove t2p_percentage like property and make a function which returns the % between t2p_conv and t2p_int. Thanks a lot for your appreciated help

Comment: @JoséCarlos: If you want to add something to the value, you should use `+=` at that point, not inside the setter. (Or write a method with a descriptive name.) Putting the `+=` inside the setter makes `thing.t2p_conv = whatever` do something completely different from what it looks like it's doing.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to remove the parentheses here:

```
print(f"result: {s.t2p_percentage}")
```

because `t2p_percentage` is declared as a `@property`.